# How to constraint type for one property with another property in the same object?

Tags: typescript

**Here is the interface for a parameter**

it's an object with the following signature:

```
interface IRenderDataToTable<T> {
  data: T[];
  titles: { [key in keyof T]: string };
  excludeProperties: (keyof T)[];
}
```

**Example data:**

- `data` is this: `{id: 1, name: 'a', age: 2}`
- `excludeProperties` will be `['id']`
- so, `titles` should be `{name: 'User Name', age: 'User Age'}`
- Because `id` has been excluded

**Problem**

Type checking mostly works, just one issue,

```
titles: { [key in keyof T]: string };
excludeProperties: (keyof T)[];
```

I want the `titles` contains `keyof T` but exclude the `key` includes in `excludeProperties`. Something like this:

```
titles: { [key in keyof Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, excludeProperties>>]: string };
```

The above declaration will leads to an error: `[ts] Cannot find name 'excludeProperties'. [2304]` which is because TS can't find where the `excludeProperties` is.

How to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is possible to do so depends on the answer to this question:

> Would `excludeProperties` change in runtime? or Do you expect to be able to change `excludeProperties` in runtime?

If the answer is "Yes", then it is impossible to do that and the reason would be explained later.

Let us first discuss the solution when the answer is "No".

If `excludeProperties` is going to be immutable in runtime, considering it's purpose is to restrict the type of `titles`, it is rather a type constraint than a value.

> **Type constraint vs value (my own understanding)**
>   **type constraint**: Saying of "*`titles` should not have keys of 'name' and 'age'*". It's a rule and is abstract. There is no need to have a concrete variable which holds `['name', 'age']`.
>   **value**: Concrete variable with value of `['name', 'age']`. It exists in the computer memory and is concrete. You can iterate over it, push new elements to it and even pop elements from it. While you do not need it if you do not need to iterate, push or pop.

So we can declare the type as

```
interface Foo<T, E extends keyof T> {
    data: T[],
    titles: { [key in Exclude<keyof T, E>]: string }
}
```

Usage:

```
interface Data {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    age: number
}


let foo: Foo<Data, 'name' | 'age'>

foo = {
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: 20 }],
    titles: {
        id: 'Title for id'
    }
}

foo = {
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: 20 }],
    titles: {
        id: 'Title for id',
        name: 'Title for name'
        // error: Type '{ id: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
    }
}

const titles = {
    id: 'Title for id',
    name: 'Title for name'
}

foo = {
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: 20 }],
    titles: titles
    // can not catch this since "Excess Property Checks" does not work in assignments
    // see: "http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks
}
```

If you do need `excludeProperties` as a variable rather than type constraint(i.e. you need the concrete value of it to iterate over or do other things), you can add it back like:

```
interface Foo<T, E extends keyof T> {
    data: T[],
    titles: { [key in Exclude<keyof T, E>]: string },
    excludeProperties: E[]
}
```

But it would not assure you the exhaustiveness of the `excludeProperties`.

```
let foo: Foo<Data, 'name' | 'age'> = {
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: 20 }],
    titles: {
        id: 'Title for id'
    },
    excludePropreties: ['name'] // is valid from the type checking perspective though 'age' is missing
}
```

Actually, as long as `titles` is provided using object literals, i.e. Excess Property Checks take effects, you can retrive the exhaustive `excludeProperties` from the `titles`: `const excludeProperties = Object.keys(foo.titles)`.

Still, exhaustiveness is not guaranteed if `titles` is provided by using another variable.

---

#### Explanation for why changing excludeProperties in runtime is impossible

Assume that we do have a type that satisfies the requirement. Then a variable like this confirms to it:

```
const foo = {
    data: { id: 1, age: 2, name: 'Alice' },
    titles: { id: 'ID', age: 'Age' },
    excludeProperties: ['name']
}
```

Then if I modify `excludeProperties`

```
foo.excludeProperties.push('age')
```

To achieve the expected constraint, type of the `foo.titles` should change to `{ id: string }` from `{ id: string, age: string }`. But, `foo.titles` do have a value of `{ id: 'ID', age: 'Age' }` and there is no way that a type system would change the value that a variable holds. There is where the imagined type collapses.

Furthur, the rule even does not hold if you wants dynamic features from it.

```
const foo = {
    data: { id: 1, age: 2, name: 'Alice' },
    titles: { id: 'ID' },
    excludeProperties: ['name', 'age']
}
```

then, If I run

```
foo.excludeProperties.pop()
```

it is impossible for `foo.titles` to make up a value for key `age` out of the air.

---

#### Update: another way of explaining the impossibility of dynamic 'excludeProperties'

The compiler cannot know what `excludeProperties` would hold in advance at compile time since it would be assigned at runtime. Thus it does not know what to exclude, and what should `titles`'s type be.

So, to make compiler be able determine what to exclude, we need to make `excludeProperties` definitive at compile time. My solution exhibited above achieves this by expressing this exclusion idea via generic type parameter which is definitive at compile time.

One may say that `Object.freeze(['id', 'name'])` is another way of expressing compile-time-definitive exclusion. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way in typescript to exploit this "definitiveness".

And my gut tells me that it is true. A static type system shall collect all it's knowledge about the code only from a static analysis, i.e. it shall not understand and assume the behavior of a certain function (`Object.freeze` in this case). As long as the type system is agnostic about the actual behavior of `Object.freeze`, which it should be, `Object.freeze(['id', 'name'])` is not a compile-time-definitive expression.

In fact, the essence of not being able to tell the compiler about type informations via an array variable is that there is no way in javascript to express an immutable array with a literal (Object.freeze is a function call, not a literal), which, however, can be exploited by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. In short, I solved the problem by introducing that extra type E.